# iOS 15, How to set alternate icon (User-Selectable App Icons)

Tags: ios, ios15, appicon

After upgrade on iOS 15 the app has lost the ability to change alternate icon ([User-Selectable App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/#user-selectable-app-icons)). I didn't find any changes in documentation. How does one set an alternate app icon on iOS 15?

Comment: From the Release Notes: "At runtime, your app can now use iOS app icon assets from its asset catalog as alternate app icons. A new build setting, “Include all app icon assets,” controls whether Xcode includes all app icon sets in the built product. When the setting is disabled, Xcode includes the primary app icon, along with the icons specified in the new setting, “Alternate app icon sets.” The asset catalog compiler inserts the appropriate content into the Info.plist of the built product."

Comment: Where do you find the new "Alternate app icon sets" setting?  I don't see it in the Build Settings tab of my Target, which is where the docs seem to indicate that it should be.  I see 'Include All App Icon Assets' (set to Yes now), and 'Primary App Icon Set Name' (set to the icon I selected), but nothing more.